# SQL Server read-replica hosted on AWS with ephemeral storage

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, aws

I have a temporary need (during transition from on-prem to AWS) to provide a high-performance SQL server instance for analytics.

I would like to purchase two SQL server enterprise instances. One instance will be a standard EC2 type backed by EBS volumes and will be the "primary" database for OLTP.

The second instance, I would like to be of an i3 type with local NVMe storage. I would like to use dynamic disks / storage spaces to put the local NVMe storage in RAID 0 and turn the instance in to a read replica (using availability groups) to do our analytics queries on.

By necessity, the read-replica will be a high end instance, while the primary DB will be a more reasonable instance size where we are less sensitive to delays.

The i3 instance type uses locally attached storage that is ephemeral. If the instance is stopped, fails, or has to move the DB storage will be lost. I would continue to maintain snapshots of the primary database, and I would use DNS to allow us to "fail back" to the primary database if the secondary database goes down for a period of time.

**Is it feasible to run an availability group like this and to restore a new instance on new storage in case of a failure?** I don't know a lot about availability groups. Recovery time and process is not a big concern here because this is a temporary solution and rebuilding the read-replica from backups is probably not too big of a deal. I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious in a failure scenario. We will need 6 months to a year to restructure our infrastructure and data to better suit our needs.

Comment: One question I would ask yourself is if the primary encounters an issue requiring a failover to the other node in the availability group are you comfortable with your primary instance running on ephemeral storage for an unknown duration?

Comment: @Aaron well, no. But the secondary is just a read replica. It’s not meant to failover to. I would keep multiple backups of the primary to recover from and if the read replica stays online we’re good.

Comment: Removing the data persistence concern for the equation, what you are proposing sounds fine. Especially if you are heavy read vs write. One thing to keep in mind with the smaller primary is that it may not be able to handle the read load should you have to fall back to it since it is a smaller instance.